# Zend Validate Int removes commas

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using the Zend_Validate_Int class to validate integers in a form.  When the number is something like 1,000 it passes validation, but then removes the comma. Does anyone know a way I can get it to keep the comma?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the comma? It should only be used for display purposes, so you format the number when you display it

Comment: I use the form to populate some xml that's used for display. The fields need to be generic, so it's much easier to format it before displaying the info.

Comment: are you using any `filters` for the form element?

Comment: Yes, Zend_Filter_StringTrim, but I don't think that would affect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Zend_Validate_Int` is not your problem.

This validator accepts a value to validate and simply returns a boolean and only a boolean. It will validate as true an integer with a comma. The comma is str_replaced to empty but that value is never returned.

Your problem may be involved with any locale you have set or with any type casting you are using.

You can dump the variable values at every step to find where the actual change takes place.

Your best bet to fix this would likely be a view helper to format the values for output.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `Zend_Validate_Int` is to make sure that final number you get is an integer not a float, you probably need to use another validator or a regular expression, or simply try `Zend_Validate_Float`.